# Inject ordered list with innerHTML in Angular

Tags: html, angular

I'm using Angular CLI v13.3.6 with Node v16.12.0 and I've a problem when I use innerHTML property.

I'm using Angular CLI v13.3.6 with Node v16.12.0.
In typescript file I've a variable with an ordered list like this:

`let myText = "<ol><li>first</li><li>second</li></ol>";`

I need to show this text in a disabled div, so this is the code that I'm using in the html file:

`<div id="myId" class="myClass" [innerHTML]="myText" disabled></div>`

The result is that the text is shown but the numbers not. The same issue is present when I use the unordered lists. How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, Angular compiler does not accept any string to be injected as HTML. You can bypass this by using DOMSanitizer to "trust" the string and parse it as valid HTML.

You will have to import DomSanitizer and inject it in yopur constructor like:

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

constructor(private readonly domSanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }
```

And then use DomSanitizer to trust your string to parse it as HTML. You can use like this:

```
this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(YOUR_STRING_HTML);
```

Comment: Thank you for you reply. I've just tried but this solution doesn't work for me. Maybe something is missing?

Comment: Can you provide your full code that you are trying to inject HTML? Maybe it´s something else...

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Sanitize html. It is CSS issue.

So to avoid overwritten CSS. You could try:

- Creating a brand new angular app: `ng new`. This way no third party CSS involved
- Open the app in `Incognito/Anonymous` mode, this will help prevent any browser extensions to interfere with your app

Answer (score 0):

Matheus Carvalho is correct that you need to sanitize the HTML for angular to inject it without warnings.

Jimmy is also correct that the root of this issue is actually CSS.

I would check to make sure your list does not have the following CSS

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

ol {
  list-style: none;
}
```

If you want there to be bullet points or numbers you will need to make sure your CSS is correct. I recommend creating a 'disabled' class that will make your HTML appear disabled. The disabled attribute can only be used on certain HTML elements, see [https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_disabled.asp#:~:text=The%20disabled%20attribute%20is%20a,a%20checkbox%2C%20etc.](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_disabled.asp#:%7E:text=The%20disabled%20attribute%20is%20a,a%20checkbox%2C%20etc.)).

### Solution

#### create a 'disabled' class

Make sure you

```css
ul {
  /* default is disc */
  list-style-type: upper-roman;
}
ol {
  /* default is decimal */
  list-style: none;
}

.disabled * {
  opacity: .5;
  pointer-events: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.disabled ol {
  list-style: decimal;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
</ul>

<ol>
  <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
</ol>

<div disabled>
  <ol>
    <li>the disabled attribute doesn't work on list elements</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
  </ol>
</div>

<div class="disabled">
  <ol>
    <li>These list items appear disabled</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```